# Computing GDP deflators over two indices

Tags: python, pandas, economics

I am working with a multi-index (country, year) dataframe in pandas containing GDP data in local currency units at current prices, eg

```
                gdp
country year    
AUS     2013    274865000000    
        2012    269562000000    
        2011    251727000000    
        2010    233604000000    
        2009    221002000000    
        2008    202260000000    
USA     2013    2550000000000
        ...     ...
```

I would like to create a new column containing the GDP deflator with 2010 as the base year, eg

```
                gdp             gdpdef
country year    
AUS     2013    274865000000    1.18
        2012    269562000000    1.15
        2011    251727000000    1.08
        2010    233604000000    1.00
        2009    221002000000    0.95
        2008    202260000000    0.87
USA     2013    2550000000000   1.01
        ...     ...             ...
        2010    2520000000000   1
        ....    ...             ...
```

Where, to be explicit, each entry in "gdpdef" is given by the ratio of GDP for country i in year t to GDP for country i in year 2010.

For a single country with the single index (year) I am able to achieve this end with:

```
base_year = df.get_value(2010, "gdp")
df["gdpdef"] = df["gdp"].div(base_year)
```

However I am having having a lot of trouble replicating this operation over the two indices (country, year) in a succinct manner. Any help toward this end is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `dict` for map index by `rename` or map column by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).

Multiindex complicated it. So in first solution use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `level=1` for column `year` and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select column `gdp`.

In second solution is no `level=1` parameter, so all index levels are converted to columns. So then is necessary [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). Last was added [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html), because different indexes in `df1` and `df`, so data are not aligned.

```
print (df)
                        gdp
country year               
AUS     2013   274865000000
        2012   269562000000
        2011   251727000000
        2010   233604000000
        2009   221002000000
        2008   202260000000
USA     2013  2550000000000
        2010  2546000000000

df1 = df.reset_index(level=1)
d = df1.loc[df1['year'] == 2010, 'gdp'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'USA': 2546000000000, 'AUS': 233604000000}

df["gdpdef"] = df["gdp"].div(df1.rename(index=d).index)
print (df)
                        gdp    gdpdef
country year                         
AUS     2013   274865000000  1.176628
        2012   269562000000  1.153927
        2011   251727000000  1.077580
        2010   233604000000  1.000000
        2009   221002000000  0.946054
        2008   202260000000  0.865824
USA     2013  2550000000000  1.001571
        2010  2546000000000  1.000000
```

---

```
df1 = df.reset_index()
d = df1[df1['year'] == 2010].set_index('country')['gdp'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'USA': 2546000000000, 'AUS': 233604000000}

df["gdpdef"] = df1["gdp"].div(df1['country'].map(d)).values
print (df)
                        gdp    gdpdef
country year                         
AUS     2013   274865000000  1.176628
        2012   269562000000  1.153927
        2011   251727000000  1.077580
        2010   233604000000  1.000000
        2009   221002000000  0.946054
        2008   202260000000  0.865824
USA     2013  2550000000000  1.001571
        2010  2546000000000  1.000000
```

---

Solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and custom function should by slowier in large `DataFrame`:

```
def f(x):
    x['gdpdef'] = x['gdp'].div(x.loc[x.index.get_level_values('year') == 2010, 'gdp'].item())
    return x

df = df.groupby(level='country').apply(f)
print (df)
                        gdp    gdpdef
country year                         
AUS     2013   274865000000  1.176628
        2012   269562000000  1.153927
        2011   251727000000  1.077580
        2010   233604000000  1.000000
        2009   221002000000  0.946054
        2008   202260000000  0.865824
USA     2013  2550000000000  1.001571
        2010  2546000000000  1.000000
```

Comment: @Ff.Graeme - Glad can help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `groupby` function in Pandas. From what I gather, you're looking to apply the 2010 deflator to each country's GDP individually by country. This would entail:

```
grouped = df.groupby("country")
for name, group in grouped:
    group["gdpdef"] = group["gdp"].div(base_year)
```